# PHP - number_format and rounding

Tags: php, rounding, number-formatting

The `number_format` function in PHP seems to round by default.  My understanding is that this function is useful for separating every three numbers with a comma.  Like 1403423 becomes 1,404,423 when using number_format.

So, if I have a large number that I want rounded to two decimal places, how can I do this and still have the commas properly displayed?

Desired behavior: 12042.529  -->  12,042.53

Comment: Um.... where?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: **If only one parameter is given, number will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

If two parameters are given, number will be formatted with decimals decimals with a dot (".") in front, and a comma (",") between every group of thousands.**

Comment: None of that talks about rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a=12042.529;
echo number_format($a,2,'.',',');
```